# Why doesn't my process die when the loop finishes executing?

Tags: erlang

Here's my code:

```
-module(area_server0).
-export([loop/0]).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").


loop() ->
    receive
        {circle, R} ->
            io:format("The area of a circle with radius ~w is: ~w~n",
                      [R, math:pi()*R*R]),
            loop();

        {rectangle, H, W} ->
            io:format("The are of a rectangle with sides ~w x ~w is: ~w~n",
                      [H, W, H*W]),
            loop();
        stop ->
            ok

    end.
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.4  (abort with ^G)

1> Pid = spawn(area_server0, loop, []).
<0.34.0>

2> i().
...
...
kernel_safe_sup       gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.32.0>              erlang:apply/2                        2586    18929    0
                      c:pinfo/1                               50              
<0.34.0>              area_server0:loop/0                    233        9    0
                      area_server0:loop/0                      1              
Total                                                      44876   318773    0
                                                             220  

3> Pid ! stop.
stop

4> i().
...
...
kernel_safe_sup       gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.32.0>              erlang:apply/2                        2586    38126    0
                      c:pinfo/1                               50              
<0.34.0>              area_server0:loop/0                    233        9    1
                      area_server0:loop/0                      1              
Total                                                      42900   355567    1
                                                         220
```

I expected not to see process <0.34.0> listed there anymore.

Now, if I alter my code to send a message that is a tuple rather than an atom, then the process dies:

```
-module(area_server0).
-export([loop/0]).
-include_lib("eunit/include/eunit.hrl").


loop() ->
    receive
        {circle, R} ->
            io:format("The area of a circle with radius ~w is: ~w~n",
                      [R, math:pi()*R*R]),
            loop();

        {rectangle, H, W} ->
            io:format("The are of a rectangle with sides ~w x ~w is: ~w~n",
                      [H, W, H*W]),
            loop();
        {stop, _Pid} ->
            ok

    end.
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V6.4  (abort with ^G)

1> c(area_server0).
{ok,area_server0}

2> Pid = spawn(area_server0, loop, []).
<0.43.0>

3> i().
...
...
kernel_safe_sup       gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.32.0>              erlang:apply/2                         987    19840    0
                      c:pinfo/1                               50              
<0.43.0>              area_server0:loop/0                    233        1    0
                      area_server0:loop/0                      1              
Total                                                      37492   862830    0
                                                             220  
ok

4> Pid ! {stop, self()}.
{stop,<0.32.0>}

5> i().
...
...
kernel_safe_sup       gen_server:loop/6                        9              
<0.32.0>              erlang:apply/2                        2586    39352    0
                      c:pinfo/1                               50              
Total                                                      38858   900091    0
                                                             219              
ok
```

Apparently, the first example is not finding a pattern match for the atom `stop`.  Why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it looks like `stop` is maybe a reserved atom in erlang.  My code works as expected if I substitute the atom `finished` or `xyz`:

```
loop() ->
    receive
        {circle, R} ->
            io:format("The area of a circle with radius ~w is: ~w~n",
                      [R, math:pi()*R*R]),
            loop();

        {rectangle, H, W} ->
            io:format("The are of a rectangle with sides ~w x ~w is: ~w~n",
                      [H, W, H*W]),
            loop();
        finished ->
            ok

    end.
```

Comment: There is nothing special with the atom 'stop'. More likely, the loaded version of the module was not the same as in your editor (maybe you forgot to recompile and/or reload it after a change). When you modified the code again, you loaded the new version and it worked. Try going back to 'stop' to see if this was the case.

Comment: @RichardC,  You are right, of course.  Now when I try my code and send the message 'stop'; the process terminates.  I usually make sure I include a `c(modname)` when I post my shell output.

Answer (score 2):

In your first code, when you call i/0 for the second time in shell

the process loop/0 mailbox is not empty (num = 1)

meaning that your stop message is not matched by the process loop/0

Make sure your order of operation is correct：

1. compile
2. spawn
3. i/0
4. send stop message
5. i/0

Comment: Hey, that's pretty clever.